# asp.net login control - set user auth ticket expiration date

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I wanna to overide expiration date of user auth ticket on login.aspx.

This code doen't work properly, because after 1 minute user is still authenticated.

```
private int loginExpire = 1;
protected void Login_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   HttpCookie authCookie = Response.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
   FormsAuthenticationTicket oldAuthTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

  var newAuthTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                oldAuthTicket.Version, 
                oldAuthTicket.Name, 
                DateTime.Now, 
                DateTime.Now.Add               
               (TimeSpan.FromMinutes(loginExpire)), 
               oldAuthTicket.IsPersistent,       
               oldAuthTicket.UserData, 
               FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);



 string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newAuthTicket);
 authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(authCookie);

 FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(GetDestinationPage(lgUserLogin.UserName), false);
}
```

web.config

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" requireSSL="false" timeout="1"         slidingExpiration="true" protection="All"/>
 </authentication>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the forms element for authentication section in web.config: set timeout="1" and slidingExpiration="false"
Or instead of RedirectFromLoginPage method use code below:

```
String returnUrl;
if (Request.QueryString["ReturnURL"] == null)
{
    returnUrl = "/Default.aspx"; //your default page url
}
else
{
    returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnURL"];
}
Response.Redirect(returnUrl);
```

Comment: Do I handle Login_LoggedIn event in your case?

Comment: Yes but you can substantially reduce it: if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(LoginControl.UserName, LoginControl.Password)){ FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(LoginControl.UserName, false); }

Comment: You can left it true but in that case you must wait more the timeout and then refresh page or perform some action that fire postback

Comment: Still doesn't work. Why do you suggest me to set slidingExpiration to false?